# Don't blend a polyline that has crossed lines with itself in webgl

Tags: webgl, alphablending, webgl2

I'm drawing two polylines (which are lines in the sample) in webgl with enabled blending.

```
gl.uniform4f(colorUniformLocation, 0, 0, 0, 0.3);

gl.enable(gl.BLEND);
gl.blendFunc(gl.ONE, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([0.2, -1, 0.2, 1,]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
gl.drawArrays(gl.LINE_STRIP, 0, 2);

gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([0, -1, 0, 1,0, -1, 0, 1]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
gl.drawArrays(gl.LINE_STRIP, 0, 4);
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/smatushonok/pen/vYBqEYq?editors=0011) is the codepen sample.

The left line are crossed with itself and it seems like it blends with itself, so as result it becomes darker.

I would like the blend to work between those polylines, but don't want a polyline to blend with itself. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use the stencil test. You'd set webgl so that the stencil stores a certain value when a pixel is drawn and you'd set the stencil test so it fails if it sees that value.

First an example that draws 2 sets of 2 overlapping triangles with blending on. The pairs will get darker where they overlap

```js
function main() {
  const m4 = twgl.m4;
  const gl = document
      .querySelector('canvas')
      .getContext('webgl');

  const vs = `
  attribute vec4 position;
  uniform mat4 matrix;
  void main() {
    gl_Position = matrix * position;
  }
  `;
  
  const fs = `
  precision mediump float;
  uniform vec4 color;
  void main() {
    gl_FragColor = color;
  }
  `;
  
  // compile shader, link program, look up locations
  const programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);
  gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
  
  // create a buffer and put data in it
  const bufferInfo = twgl.createBufferInfoFromArrays(gl, {
    position: {
      numComponents: 2,
      data: [
        -0.5, -0.2,
         0.5, -0.2,
         0.5,  0.2,
         
        -0.2, -0.5,
        -0.2,  0.5,
         0.2,  0.5,
      ],
    },
  });
  
  gl.enable(gl.BLEND);
  gl.blendFunc(gl.ONE, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
  
  // calls gl.bindBuffer, gl.enableVertexAttribArray, gl.vertexAttribPointer
  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);
  
  // calls gl.uniform??
  twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, {
    color: [0.5, 0, 0, 0.5],
    matrix: m4.identity(),
  });
  
  // calls gl.drawArrays or gl.drawElements
  twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, bufferInfo);
  
  twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, {
    color: [0, 0, 0.5, 0.5],
    matrix: m4.rotateZ(
        m4.translation([-0.1, 0.2, 0]),
        Math.PI * 1.2),
  });
  twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, bufferInfo);
}
main();
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

Then the same example with the stencil test on

First we need to ask for a stencil buffer

```
  const gl = someCanvas.getContext('webgl2', {stencil: true});
```

Then we turn on the stencil test

```
  gl.enable(gl.STENCIL_TEST);
```

Set up the test so it only draws if the stencil buffer is zero

```
  gl.stencilFunc(
     gl.EQUAL,   // the test
     0,          // reference value
     0xFF,       // mask
  );
```

And set the operation so we increment the stencil when we draw so they will no longer be zero and therefore fail the test

```
  gl.stencilOp(
     gl.KEEP,  // what to do if the stencil test fails
     gl.KEEP,  // what to do if the depth test fails
     gl.INCR,  // what to do if both tests pass
  );
```

Between the first draw and the second we clear the stencil buffer

```
gl.clear(gl.STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);
```

Example

```js
function main() {
  const m4 = twgl.m4;
  const gl = document
      .querySelector('canvas')
      .getContext('webgl', {stencil: true});

  const vs = `
  attribute vec4 position;
  uniform mat4 matrix;
  void main() {
    gl_Position = matrix * position;
  }
  `;
  
  const fs = `
  precision mediump float;
  uniform vec4 color;
  void main() {
    gl_FragColor = color;
  }
  `;
  
  // compile shader, link program, look up locations
  const programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);
  gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
  
  // create a buffer and put data in it
  const bufferInfo = twgl.createBufferInfoFromArrays(gl, {
    position: {
      numComponents: 2,
      data: [
        -0.5, -0.2,
         0.5, -0.2,
         0.5,  0.2,
         
        -0.2, -0.5,
        -0.2,  0.5,
         0.2,  0.5,
      ],
    },
  });
  
  gl.enable(gl.BLEND);
  gl.blendFunc(gl.ONE, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
  
  gl.enable(gl.STENCIL_TEST);
  gl.stencilFunc(
     gl.EQUAL,  // the test
     0,         // reference value
     0xFF,      // mask
  );
  gl.stencilOp(
     gl.KEEP,    // what to do if the stencil test fails
     gl.KEEP,    // what to do if the depth test fails
     gl.INCR,    // what to do if both tests pass
  );
  
  
  // calls gl.bindBuffer, gl.enableVertexAttribArray, gl.vertexAttribPointer
  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);
  
  // calls gl.uniform??
  twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, {
    color: [0.5, 0, 0, 0.5],
    matrix: m4.identity(),
  });
  
  // calls gl.drawArrays or gl.drawElements
  twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, bufferInfo);
  
  gl.clear(gl.STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);  
  
  twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, {
    color: [0, 0, 0.5, 0.5],
    matrix: m4.rotateZ(
        m4.translation([-0.1, 0.2, 0]),
        Math.PI * 1.2),
  });
  twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, bufferInfo);
}
main();
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

Another solution you could also use the depth test if you're drawing 2D stuff. The default depth test only draws if the depth is `gl.LESS` than the current depth so just turning the depth test on and setting a different depth between draws would also work if the depth of the triangles is the same. You could compute a different depth value for each thing you draw, you'd need to look up the bit resolution of the depth buffer. Or, you could use `gl.polygonOffset`

```
gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
gl.enable(gl.POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL); 

... then ...

for (let i = 0; i < numThingsToDraw; ++i) {
  gl.polygonOffset(0, -i);  // each thing 1 depth unit less
  draw2DThing(things[i]);
}
```

example

```js
function main() {
  const m4 = twgl.m4;
  const gl = document
      .querySelector('canvas')
      .getContext('webgl');
  
  const vs = `
  attribute vec4 position;
  uniform mat4 matrix;
  void main() {
    gl_Position = matrix * position;
  }
  `;
  
  const fs = `
  precision mediump float;
  uniform vec4 color;
  void main() {
    gl_FragColor = color;
  }
  `;
  
  // compile shader, link program, look up locations
  const programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);
  gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
  
  // create a buffer and put data in it
  const bufferInfo = twgl.createBufferInfoFromArrays(gl, {
    position: {
      numComponents: 2,
      data: [
        -0.5, -0.2,
         0.5, -0.2,
         0.5,  0.2,
         
        -0.2, -0.5,
        -0.2,  0.5,
         0.2,  0.5,
      ],
    },
  });
  
  gl.enable(gl.BLEND);
  gl.blendFunc(gl.ONE, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
  
  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
  gl.enable(gl.POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL);
  
  // calls gl.bindBuffer, gl.enableVertexAttribArray, gl.vertexAttribPointer
  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);
  
  // calls gl.uniform??
  twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, {
    color: [0.5, 0, 0, 0.5],
    matrix: m4.identity(),
  });
  
  // calls gl.drawArrays or gl.drawElements
  twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, bufferInfo);

  gl.polygonOffset(0, -1);
  
  twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, {
    color: [0, 0, 0.5, 0.5],
    matrix: m4.rotateZ(
        m4.translation([-0.1, 0.2, 0.0]),
        Math.PI * 1.2),
  });
  twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, bufferInfo);
}
main();
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks you a lot for this clear and comprehensive answer! The stencil way works great for me.